# codeigniter Json table in view page not loading table

Tags: mysql, json, codeigniter, crud

trying to set crud with incodeigniter. I have never done it so I don't understand where I have gone wrong. I am able to insert data into the database and the *insert data window* is shown. I attached a picture of the result. The data gets retrieved from the database but not loaded into the table.

[image: screenshot]

Result:
[image: result screenshot]

**CONTROLLER**

```
    function  get($id = null){
        $this->load->model('model_peca');
        $this->load->model('model_perfil'); 
        //  $this->load->view('telas/pecas/view_addvalue');         
        if ($id !=null) {

        $data = $this->model_peca->getData($id);



        } else {                    
        $data = $this->model_peca->getData();
            }

            $dados ['telaativa'] = 'pecas';
            $dados ['tela'] = 'pecas/view_addvalue';
            $this->load->view('view_home', $dados);
        echo json_encode($data->result_object());

        }


    function edit($id){
     $this->load->model('model_peca');
    $data = $this->model_peca->getData($id)->result_object();

    // }
    // else{

        $this->load->view('telas/pecas/view_edit',array('data'=>$data));
    // }
    }

function add(){
                //$this->load->view('insert');
                $this->load->model('model_peca');
                $this->load->view('telas/pecas/view_insert');
}

 function insert(){
    $this->load->model('model_peca');
            if ($this->input->post()) {
        $peca_parent_id = $this->input->post('peca_parent_id');
        $nr_peca = $this->input->post('nr_peca');
         //echo $peca_parent_id;
        // die;
        $insert = $this->model_peca->insert($peca_parent_id,$nr_peca);
        if ($insert > 0) {
            $result = 200;
        }
        else{
            $result = 0;
        }
        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
}
}

    function deleteoperacao($id){

        $delete = $this->model_peca->delete($id);
        if ($delete > 0) {
            $result = 200;
        }
        else{
            $result = 0;
        }
        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
    }

        function update($id){
            if ($this->input->post()) {
        $peca_parent_id = $this->input->post('peca_parent_id');
        $nr_peca = $this->input->post('nr_peca');
        // echo $barang;
        $insert = $this->model_peca->update($id,$peca_parent_id,$nr_peca);
        if ($insert > 0) {
            $result = 200;
        }
        else{
            $result = 0;
        }
        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
function getData($id =null){
    if ($id ==null) {
    $data = $this->db->get('peca_value');
    }
    else{
    $data = $this->db->get_where('peca_value',array('id'=>$id));
    }
    return $data;
    }

    function insert($peca_parent_id,$nr_peca){
    $data = array('peca_parent_id'=>$peca_parent_id,'nr_peca'=>$nr_peca);
    return $this->db->insert('peca_value', $data);
    }


    function update($id,$peca_parent_id,$nr_peca){
    $data = array('peca_parent_id'=>$peca_parent_id,'nr_peca'=>$nr_peca);
    $where = array('id'=>$id);
    return $this->db->update('peca_value', $data,$where);
    }

    function delete($id){
    $where = array('id'=>$id);
    return $this->db->delete('peca_value',$where);
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <section class="content-header">

        <h1>Lista Peças 


        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
              <li>Peças</li>
              <li class="active">Lista pecas</li>

        </ol>
  </section>
  </head>         
  <body>


<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-act" data-name='add'  href="<?php echo base_url('Home/add') ?>"> Nova Operação</button>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <h1></h1>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th>peca_parent_id</th><th>nr_peca</th><th>Editar/Apagar</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="wrap">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">

  </div>
 </div>

 </div>
```

```
   <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------->




<style type="text/css">
body{
    background: #eee;
}
</style>


<script src="../assets/js/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>


<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    list();

$(document).on('click',".update",function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('Home/update'); ?>"+$(this).data('id'),
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            peca_parent_id: $(".name").val(),
            nr_peca: $(".price").val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(r){

            if (r.result ==200) {
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                list();
            }
        }
    });
    });

    $(document).on('click',".insert",function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('Home/insert'); ?>",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            peca_parent_id: $(".name").val(),
            nr_peca: $(".price").val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(r){

            if (r.result ==200) {
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                list();
            }
        }
    });
    });
   $(document).on('click','.btn-delete',function(){
   $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("href"),
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(r){
        if (r.result == 200) {
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                list();
        }
    }
});
});


    function list(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('Home/get'); ?>",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(r){
                var html ='';
                var i;

                for (i = 0;i < r.length; i++) {
                    html += "<tr>";     

                    html += "<td>"+r[i].peca_parent_id+"</td>";
                    html += "<td>"+r[i].nr_peca+"</td>";
                    html += "<td><button data-name='edit' class='btn btn-act btn-update btn-success' href='<?php echo base_url('Home/edit'); ?>"+r[i].id+"'>Edit</button> <button  class='btn-act btn btn-danger' data-name='delete' href='<?php echo base_url('Home/deleteoperacao'); ?>"+r[i].id+"'>Hapus</button></td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                }
                $("#wrap").html(html);

            }
        });
    }
    });


// aksi btn-act 
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-act",function(){
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    // jika data-name sama dengan edit;
    if (name=='edit') {
                $("#myModal .modal-title").html("Edit Data");

    $("#myModal .modal-body").load($(this).attr('href'));
    $("#myModal").modal('show');

    $("#myModal .modal-footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-close" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>')
    }
    if (name=='add') {
    $("#myModal .modal-title").html("Tambah Data");

    $("#myModal .modal-body").load($(this).attr('href'));
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#myModal .modal-footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-close" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>')
    }
    if(name=='delete'){
    $("#myModal .modal-title").html("Konfirmasi");      
    $("#myModal .modal-body").html("Apakah Anda Akan Menghapusnya?");
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#myModal .modal-footer").html('<button href="'+href+'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete" data-dismiss="modal">Hapus</button>')
    }
      });
```

Comment: your error is most liekely somwehere here: `$this->load->view('view_home', $dados); echo json_encode($data->result_object());` You can use console.dir(r) to analyze the `success` part of your ajax function

Comment: $this->load->view('view_home', $dados); confirmed and got ito work thanks